# CreateFileMapping() name

Tags: c++, character-encoding, char

Im creating a DLL that shares memory between different applications.

The code that creates the shared memory looks like this:

```
#define NAME_SIZE 4
HANDLE hSharedFile;

create(char[NAME_SIZE] name)
{
    hSharedFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1024, (LPCSTR)name);
    (...) //Other stuff that maps the view of the file etc.
}
```

It does not work. However if I replace `name` with a string it works:

```
SharedFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1024, (LPCSTR)"MY_TEST_NAME");
```

How can I get this to work with the char array?

I have a java background where you would just use string all the time, what is a LPCSTR? And does this relate to whether my MS VC++ project is using `Unicode` or `Multi-Byte` character set

Comment: What is the value of char array (`name`) you are passing in `create`? What is the return value and error code (you can get it with `GetLastError`) of `CreateFileMapping` when it fails?

Comment: What are you passing as a parameter to create function?

Comment: I am passing {'T', 'E', 'S', 'T'}, it does not fail, but I can not open the shared memory space later in another app.

Comment: See my Answer please. You must increase NAME_SIZE to be at least 5 and pass '\0' at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should increase `NAME_SIZE` value.

Do not forget that array must be at least number of chars + 1 to hold \0 char at the end, which shows the end of the line.

LPCSTR is a pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 8-bit Windows (ANSI) characters and defined as follows:

```
LPCSTR defined as typedef __nullterminated CONST CHAR *LPCSTR;
```

For example even if you have `"Hello world"` constant and it has 11 characters it will take 12 bytes in the memory.

If you are passing a string constant as an array you must add '\0' to the end like `{'T','E','S','T', '\0'}`

Comment: Thanks, I increased the size, but to me it seems unlogical that it must have '\0' as the last character.

Comment: you can read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string to find more information about strings in C

Comment: You wrote that you have exp. with Java. This is why it is a little but confusing for you. Java is using null terminated string inside the VM and wrap it into Java string class.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation, you'll find that most Win32 functions take an `LPCTSTR`, which represents a string of `TCHAR`. Depending on whether you use Unicode (the default) or ANSI, `TCHAR` will expand to either `wchar_t` or `char`. Also, `LPCWSTR` and `LPCSTR` explicitly represent Unicode and ANSI strings respectively.

When you're developing for Win32, in most cases, it's best to follow suit and use `LPCTSTR` wherever you need strings, instead of explicit `char` arrays/pointers. Also, use the `TEXT("...")` macro to create the correct kind of string literals instead of just `"..."`.

In your case though, I doubt this is causing a problem, since both your examples use only `LPCSTR`. You have also defined `NAME_SIZE` to be 4, could it be that your array is too small to hold the string you want?